# Full height border?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I set full height of border without setting fixed height?

The contents of `<div class="col-md-9"></div>` are quite large, on the sidebar (`<div class="col-md-3"> </div`) a red border should expand vertically.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38699/

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
                <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
                <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
                <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="border">
                    <p>Sidebar</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.border {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: what about just adding another div with a background color?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Not a very clear question

Comment: Why do you want to expand the sidebar with a red border? Why not just make the div itself taller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you switch your `.border` class from `.col-md-3` to `.col-md-9` and change `border-left` to `border-right` in `.border`

```css
.border {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9">
        <div class="border">
          <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
          <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
          <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
          <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
        <p>Sidebar</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```